# Set window icon correctly and happening XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf

I set window icon property in xaml code or in the properties window correctly in a very simple wpf application, but visual studio always throws an XamlParseException at runtime. Why is this happening?(using visual studio 2013 and windows 8,  my icon size is 15 KB)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Icon="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/MyIcon.ico">
<Grid>

</Grid> </Window>

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Icon="/Resources/MyIcon.ico">
<Grid>

</Grid> </Window>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it all XAML code? Where is closing </window> tag at the end?

Comment: @rufanov sorry I missed it here

Comment: Whats the exception?

Comment: @Ganesh XamlParseException

Comment: is thr any inner exception?

Comment: what is the line number ? Btw there should not be any exception.. Do you have .ico image in you Resources folder ?

Comment: @Ganesh no ...........

Comment: @loop Yes, of course I have an icon image in the resource folder .

Comment: please post the screenshot of Exception expended view..

Comment: @loop Unfortunately my rating is 7 and  I need 10 to post picture . thank you for your favor :)

Comment: @Mojtaba you got more than 10 now :)

Comment: @loop thanks a lot I post pictures now :)

Comment: @Mojtaba last check, try to provide some other icon but this time use .png files in place of .ico file..

Comment: @loop I changed it to a PNG file and unfortunately no difference. Meanwhile build action is "page" and I tried all options

Comment: @Mojtaba show you MainWindow.xaml.cs with namespace inculded..

Comment: For me I set the icon via the window properties interface but it didn't work. I changed `pack://siteoforigin...` to `pack://application...` and it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a problem with your image Build Action Property, check the arrows for further info..

[image]